# How to debug click event is not trigger on mobile phone?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code here where it works perfectly on my local Macbook pro, simulated test as mobile phone in Google Chrome. But when I deploy it, and clicked on the mobile phone itself, no event seems to be detected, it's like it ignore click event completely.

```
//show age diff
var showAgeDiff = false; 
var oldText = $( "#age").text();
var sdt = new Date('{{ $baby->babyDob }}');
var difdt = new Date(new Date() - sdt);
var babyAgeToCurrentDate = (difdt.toISOString().slice(0, 4) - 1970) + "Y " + (difdt.getMonth()+1) + "M " + difdt.getDate() + "D";

$("#age, #babyNameMobile").click(function() {
    showAgeDiff = !showAgeDiff

    if(showAgeDiff){
        $( "#age" ).text(babyAgeToCurrentDate);

    } else {
        $( "#age" ).text(oldText);
    }
});
```

## Live View

https://mybabies.app/baby/a4b7efe4-9c2f-4c48-b5b1-cc516a8f027f?code=krR4Mn

[image]

## Desktop

No issue, works as expected. It change from `"~8 weeks"` --> `0Y 3M 1D`

## Mobile only

If you clicked on the age area, click event will not trigger.
It should change from `"~8 weeks"` --> `0Y 3M 1D`

---

## Disclaimer :

- Android Phone ✅
- iPhone ❌

Comment: Maybe increase the "area" of where your finger is supposed to touch. I had a hard time of clicking that area on a desktop screen for example.

Comment: How would one do that ?

Comment: That content is wrapped in something. Increase the height of it.

Comment: But Android phone seem working fine, I tested on my Google Pixel phone.

Comment: Maybe the android has some additional padding around it not present on your iPhone. All you have to do is to test it to be sure.

Comment: I don't know how to test or even inspect element on my iPhone or Android. Do you guys know ?

Comment: You could put a border around the element in question (so you can see it's dimens), then increase its height so to test if it resoves the iPhone issue.

Comment: Likely tho its a cross browser issue on that click event. Research "jquery click event iOS"